# Is $(1-ne^{-cn})^4 \approx 1-e^{-cn} ?$ right for some constants $c$.?

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

> How can I get 
>   $$(1-ne^{-cn})^4 \approx 1-e^{-cn} ?$$
>   for some constants $c$.

It seems that 
$$(1-ne^{-cn})^4\geq 1-n^4 e^{-cn}$$

Here "$\approx$" means $(1-ne^{-cn})^4 \leq C( 1-e^{-cn})$ and $C(1-ne^{-cn})^4 \geq ( 1-e^{-cn})$.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "$\approx$"

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks. I add the explanation of the notation $\approx$.

Comment: For what range of $n$? When $n$ is large enough that $\max\{1,n\}e^{-cn} \le \frac12$, we trivially have $(1-ne^{-cn})^4 \approx 1 \approx 1-e^{-cn}$.

Comment: "some constants $c$" -- Your use of the plural, "constants", seems to indicate that you mean two (or more) different "$c$"s all confusingly given the same name.  Is that really what you mean?

Comment: "Here '$\approx$' means" -- You use the same symbol, "$C$" twice.  Do you intend them to be the same value, because that is not possible.  Additionally, do you want these inequalities to hold (1) for all $n < N$ (i.e. as $n \rightarrow -\infty$), (2) for all $|n| < N$ (i.e., as $n \rightarrow 0$), (3) for all $n > N$ (i.e., as $n \rightarrow \infty$), or (4) for all $n$.  Is $n$ a natural number, real number, integer, complex number?

Comment: @EricTowers Sorry, they are different contants $C$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
(1 - n z)^4 &= 1 - 4nz + 6 n^2 z^2-4 n^3 z^3 + n^4 z^4  \\
    &= 1 - \mathrm{e}^{\ln(4n)}z + \mathrm{e}^{\ln(6 n^2)} z^2 \\
    &\quad {}- \mathrm{e}^{\ln(4 n^3)} z^3 + \mathrm{e}^{\ln(n^4)} z^4  \\
\end{align*}
Substitute $z = \mathrm{e}^{-cn}$.
\begin{align*}
(1 - n \mathrm{e}^{-cn})^4 
    &= 1 - \mathrm{e}^{\ln(4n)}\mathrm{e}^{-cn} + \mathrm{e}^{\ln(6 n^2)} \mathrm{e}^{-2cn} \\
    &\quad {}- \mathrm{e}^{\ln(4 n^3)} \mathrm{e}^{-3cn} + \mathrm{e}^{\ln(n^4)} \mathrm{e}^{-4cn}  \\
    &= 1 - \mathrm{e}^{\ln(4n)-cn} + \mathrm{e}^{\ln(6 n^2)-2cn} \\
    &\quad {}- \mathrm{e}^{\ln(4 n^3)-3cn} + \mathrm{e}^{\ln(n^4)-4cn}  \\
\end{align*}

(Further progress must wait until the Question is clarified.)

Comment: Why not use the inequality $(1-e^{x})^{\alpha}\geq 1- e^{x\alpha}$?

Comment: @BobOakley : That inequality is false at $x = 1, \alpha = -1$ (or pretty much anywhere else in that quadrant).  You have given no bounds on $x$ and $\alpha$ and have not responded to clarifying questions about which $n$s your Question concerns.

Comment: Sorry for that, here $\alpha>0, x>0$. Actually, I just want to add some condition to get the inequality.